# How to call node app from regular html/js based application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

I am using this quickstart code on GitHub from Twilio (https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-js/tree/master) I am trying to create the ability for users to video chat in my application using the "programmable video" functionality.  The Twilio quickstart starter code seems to be a node app.  I can run the app by going into the directory on my windows machine and running "npm install and then npm start", this loads the app on localhost:3000/.  I am new to node, but it seems to be running on express.

My traditional HTML website runs at http://www.example.com and the node app is in a directory off the main website at http://www.example.com/videoapp

I want to have an HTML button on my website that when clicked will "run" the node app.  I am confused about how to run it this way as the instructions required me to run it from the command line using "npm start" in the /videoapp directory.

How can I click a button on my website that calls the node app?

My website runs on port 80 like most public websites, but the node app is running on port 3000 currently.

Comment: Have you thought about using iframes? Am not sure that's what you want but it might be

Comment: Iframes come with a host of issues, ideally something a bit more seamless.

Comment: On click of that button, may be `location.href = 'http://www.example.com/videoapp'`?

Comment: The user is logging into my website and has the concept of a session.  The user will be "joining a room" similar to a zoom meeting or other type of video chat.  My hope is that the two operate more cohesively if that makes sense.

Comment: What is your existing application built in?

Comment: My existing site is a php application with a mix of html, css, and javascript @philnash

Comment: OK, so you don't need to run a Node app as well, you can integrate Twilio Video into your existing application. I'd recommand taking a swing through [the Twilio Video documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/javascript-getting-started) to understand how you can integrate it rather than bolt on the quickstart app.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As the application you are looking at is a quick start application, I wouldn't recommend shipping it straight into production. For a start there is no authentication and open access to any video room. Running `npm start` runs a whole bunch of example applications too, not just the one.

The Node.js server application generates an access token to give users access to the Video rooms. If you aren't used to running Node.js applications, you don't need to. We have documentation that shows how to [generate Access Tokens to grant your users access to a room in a selection of languages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/access-tokens).

To get a better idea of how you can integrate Twilio Video to your application, I would [start with the documentation here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/basic-concepts#the-twilio-programmable-video-platform).